# Are disjoint non-trivial simple closed curves in an orientable closed surface homologous?

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $F$ be an orientable closed surface. Let $a$ and $b$ be two simple closed curves in $F$ such that $a$ and $b$ are disjoint and $[a] \neq 0$ and $[b]\neq 0$ in the first homology group of $F$, $H_1(F)$. Is it true that $[a] \cong [b]$ in $H_1(F)$. If so how to prove it.

I know the answer for the above question is true for a genus one surface (torus), but even for the torus, I don't know how to prove it. Could you please give me a hint to prove the genus one case and in general if it is true.

Comment: I believe you mean that $F$ is an orientable closed **surface**.

Answer (score 2):

It is not true. If $F$ is a closed orientable surface of genus $g$ then you can disjointly embed $g$ curves $a_1,...,a_g$ such that $F-\{a_1,...a_g\}$ is connected, in which case the homology classes $[a_1],...,[a_{g}]$ are linearly independent in $H_1(F)$.

The proof uses CW homology, by using a CW decomposition the 1-skeleton of which contains the curves $a_1,...,a_g$.

Or, for a different proof, you can construct curves $b_1,...,b_g$ so that $a_i \cap b_j = \emptyset$ if $i \ne j$ and $a_i,b_i$ intersect transversely in a single point. Using the intersection pairing on 1st homology it follows that $[a_1],...,[a_g]$ are linearly independent.

Comment: But it is true for genus on surface (torus), isn't it?

Comment: Yes, on the torus it is true. In fact, for any disjoint pair of oriented, simple closed curves on the torus, each is homotopic to the other up to reversal of direction.